# How to generate XML path within CASE

Tags: sql-server, case, for-xml-path

Edit: Trying to query a XML Path list that has been narrowed down by a case statement.  Column 'displayname' contains over 700 unique values throughout the database. However, based on other criteria including the AccountID and if RenderedValue is = '', the remaining results will most likely be less than 5. The variables in my query is I cannot explicitly declare an Account Id or DisplayName.

I have a successful CASE statement on it's own. But trying to also have the XML PATH statement pulls all the data from the table and comma separates it instead of just the results from the previous CASE statement. Can't figure out how to nest them together. Besides the GUID in column 1, values are nvarchar.

Query w/o CASE

```
select tb1.AccountID,
 tb3.DisplayName,
 tb4.RenderedValue


from Accounts tb1

join Display tb2 on tb2.AccountID = tb1.AccountID
inner join ExtractDetail tb3 on tb3.ExtractID = tb2.ExtractID
left join ExtractDetailData tb4 on tb4.ExtractDetailID = tb3.ExtractDetailID
```

result:

```
+-----------+---------------+-----------------------+
| AccountID |  DisplayName  |     RenderedValue     |
+-----------+---------------+-----------------------+
| E8175     | FirstName     | John                  |
| E8175     | LastName      | Smith                 |
| E8175     | StreetAddress | 123 Washington Street |
| E8175     | City          |                       |
| E8175     | State         | NY                    |
| E8175     | ZipCode       |                       |
| E8175     | PhoneNumber   | 555-555-5555          |
| E8175     | Email         | JohnSmith@aol.com     |
+-----------+---------------+-----------------------+
```

Query w/ CASE

```
select tb1.AccountID,
    CASE When tb4.RenderedValue = ''
    Then tb3.DisplayName
    Else ''
  End As MissingField

from Accounts tb1

join Display tb2 on tb2.AccountID = tb1.AccountID
inner join ExtractDetail tb3 on tb3.ExtractID = tb2.ExtractID
left join ExtractDetailData tb4 on tb4.ExtractDetailID = tb3.ExtractDetailID

Where tb4.RenderedValue =''
```

Result:

```
+-----------+--------------+
| AccountID | MissingField |
+-----------+--------------+
| E8175     | City         |
| E8175     | ZipCode      |
+-----------+--------------+
```

Expected Output:

```
+-----------+--------------+
| AccountID | MissingField |
+-----------+--------------+
| E8175     | City,ZipCode |
+-----------+--------------+
```

Comment: The simplest answer for you is to move to using MySQL or Postgres, both of which are free and have a built in function to do this.

Comment: Unfortunately, due to my spot in the company chain and permissions, I can't move/link databases. So I have to work within the confines of Management Studio.

Answer (score 0):

```
i think this code will help you 
create table  #temp (AccountID varchar(20),DisplayName varchar(20),RenderedValue   varchar(255))
 insert into #temp (AccountID,DisplayName,RenderedValue) values 
 ('E8175','FirstName','John')
 insert into #temp (AccountID,DisplayName,RenderedValue)  values 
 ('E8175','LastName','Smith')
 insert into #temp (AccountID,DisplayName,RenderedValue) values 
 ('E8175','StreetAddress','123 Washington Street')

 insert into #temp (AccountID,DisplayName,RenderedValue) values ('E8175','City','')
 insert into #temp (AccountID,DisplayName,RenderedValue)  values        
 ('E8175','State','NY')
 insert into #temp (AccountID,DisplayName,RenderedValue)  values 
 ('E8175','ZipCode','')
 insert into #temp (AccountID,DisplayName,RenderedValue)  values 
 ('E8175','PhoneNumber','555-555-5555 ')
 insert into #temp (AccountID,DisplayName,RenderedValue)  values 
 ('E8175','Email','JohnSmith@aol.com')





  SELECT distinct
P.AccountID,
STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT ',' +  case when RenderedValue = '' Then DisplayName Else '' End  
        FROM #temp M

        FOR XML PATH(''), type
    ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, ''
     ) AS Temp
     FROM
    #temp P


  Drop table #temp
```